# Microsoft 365 depreciation of legacy authentication, emails not now coming through

Tags: inbound-email

Our processing inbound emails is failing as Microsoft have stopped using IMAP due to authentication security issues, (I don't understand the technicalities just that it isn't working), has anyone found a solution to this issue?  I think it was on the cards for a while but we weren't aware of the implications so are now stuck. We are on 5.52.2 .

Answer (score 0):

It's not that they've stopped IMAP exactly, it's that the login method can't just be username/password. You'll need to turn on OAUTH and recreate the mail account: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/oauth/#enable-the-module